# Save and Read NSArray from NSUserDefaults using Struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a string using a struct and `NSUserDefaults`, and everything goes well.

However I'm not able to do the same for a `NSArray`.

This is my code,

**The Struct :**

```
struct ServiceKey{
static let XX : NSArray = ["xx"]
}
```

**To save :**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var first = denominationsALFA as! NSArray
defaults.setObject(first, forKey: ServiceKey.XX)
```

**To read :**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.arrayForKey(ServiceKey.XX)
```

so what could be the best solution for this problem

Comment: Key for NSUserDefaults need to be a string not array of string.

Comment: i try to make it as : static let XX : NSArray = "xx" but it give me a error: String is not convertible to NSArray @Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the syntax of method `setObject(:forKey:)` here `forKey` is is type of `String` parameter, so change you `XX` type to `String` from `NSArray` then use `setObject` and `arrayForKey` methods.

```
struct ServiceKey{
    static let XX: String = "xx"
}
```

Now Set object in `NSUserDefaults`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var first = denominationsALFA as! NSArray
defaults.setObject(first, forKey: ServiceKey.XX)
```

Retrieve object from `NSUserDefaults`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var array = defaults.arrayForKey(ServiceKey.XX)
```

For more details check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc) on `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

What i meant is, you need to use 'key' as a String and not as a Array of string.
Use this to save Key.
Others things can remain the same.

`struct ServiceKey{
   static let XX = "xx"
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using the array as the key (and first as the value). The key should be a String, so it will use the description of the Array-instance.
When you fetch the description can be different. So to make it work: use a String as a key, and an (NS)Array as the value.
In your case:
-ServiceKey.XX should be a String
-first should be an array